In Python, after a function call triggers an except block, how to immediately break out of the current loop and proceed to the next loop?
Here is a Python script below:
for item in [n1,n2,n3]:
    f1(args1)
    f2(args2)
    f3(args3)

The structure of the three functions is similar.
def f1(args):
    try:
        doing something
    except:
        pass

For the functions f1, f2, and f3, if an except is triggered during the execution of any of these functions, how can I ensure that the current loop is immediately interrupted and the next loop is entered?

You can use try, except and continue on your loop.

The loop won't know about exceptions in those function, if you catch and suppress any and all exceptions in the functions. You need to let errors bubble up to the caller ("the loop").

I think restructuring your functions like this would be more Pythonic:
import numpy as np

items = [range(10), range(10), range(10)]

def f1():
    print(1 / np.random.randint(0,2))

        
def f2():
    print(1 / np.random.randint(0,2))

        
def f3():
    print(1 / np.random.randint(0,2))


for item in items:
    try:
        f1()
        f2()
        f3()
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        print("Error: ", e, "Exiting loop")
        continue

Error:  division by zero Exiting loop
Error:  division by zero Exiting loop
1.0
Error:  division by zero Exiting loop


You may want to handle the exception in the f1, f2 and f3 functions as well as continue the higher level loop in case there's a problem.
In that case you can re-raise the exception.
Here's a pattern that you can use:
import random

def f1(a: int) -> float:
    try:
        return a / random.randint(0, 3)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Divide by zero in f1")
        raise

def f2(a: int) -> float:
    try:
        return a / random.randint(0, 3)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Divide by zero in f2")
        raise

for x in range(1, 5):
    try:
        f1(x)
        f2(x)
    except Exception:
        pass # or continue - the effect would be the same

The f1 and f2 functions are functionally identical except for the error text. An example of output might be:
Divide by zero in f1
Divide by zero in f2
Divide by zero in f1

